# How to use pojo to find out class level Log4J appender

Tags: java, log4j

Let's say there are following configurations

```
...
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.com.app.me.Myclass=FILE
....
```

I know how to find the root category appender `CONSOLE`

```
Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
Enumeration<Appender> appenders = rootLogger.getAllAppenders();
while(appenders.hasMoreElements()){
    //....
}
```

however, how can I get the class level appender? I try following code in `MyClass`

```
Logger classLogger= Logger.getLogger(Myclass.class);
Enumeration<Appender> appenders = classLogger.getAllAppenders();
while(appenders.hasMoreElements()){
    //....
}
```

`appenders` always contains no appender.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
log4j.logger.com.app.me.Myclass=DEBUG, myappender
log4j.additivity.com.app.me.Myclass=false

log4j.appender.myappender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myappender.datePattern='-'dd'.log'
log4j.appender.myappender.File=log/mylog.log
log4j.appender.myappender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myappender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%-6r %d{ISO8601} %-5p %40.40c %x - %m\n
```